# How to get the last inserted record identifier in SAP HANA database?

Tags: hana

Here is my stored procedure, I am trying to get the last inserted `DepartmentId`. Not looking for a trigger and any solution without `MAX(DepartmentId)`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "BPPRA_CUSTOM_APP"."AddUpdateMaster_Department"(IN DepartmentId BIGINT,Department nvarchar(100),Description nvarchar(100),UserId int)
    LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
    --READS SQL DATA 
AS
BEGIN
    if DepartmentId>0
    then
        update "BPPRA_CUSTOM_APP"."Master_Department" set "Department"=Department,"Description"=Description ,"ModifiedUserId"=UserId,"ModifiedDate"=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
        where "DepartmentId"= :DepartmentId;
        select  DepartmentId  FROM DUMMY;
    ELSE    
    
    insert into "BPPRA_CUSTOM_APP"."Master_Department" ("Department","Description","CreatedUserId","CreatedDate") 
                                                 values(Department,Description,UserId,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);   
        
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Your procedure seems to be doing an `UPDATE` for already existing records and an `INSERT` for non-existing records. There are two SAP HANA SQL commands available that do this without the need for a procedure: `MERGE` and `UPSERT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the insert query just use this:

`select current_identity_value() FROM DUMMY;`

It will return the latest inserted value

Comment: How to accomplish this when inserting multiple records?  MSSQL has OUTPUT. SAP HANA has?